# What's inside this current limiter?

Tags: transformer, current-limiting, toroidal

This component was inside an isolation transformer. It's obviously for limiting inrush current, but how does it work and what is inside?

I believe it's a relay of some sort, switching a resistor in series with the input or something like that. When voltage are applied to it's input i can hear the relay inside oscillating, so clearly somethings wrong. Makes me wonder how it triggers on the inrush current and why they didn't go for a NTC current limiter.

Thanks :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: That brown spot on the front probably means something inside overheated.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost surely some kind of impedance (a power resistor or an NTC thermistor) with a time-delay relay contact shunting the resistance.

That way the power consumption in steady state is small- perhaps 0.4W- mostly just the relay coil and the control circuitry.

The relay contact simply closes a short time after power is applied.